# Add RAID to Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 SP1 That Boots VHD From USB Flash Drive

Tags: raid, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Is there anyway to add RAID after the fact to an VHD install? I used this guideline http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee731893%28WS.10%29.aspx to create the OS and everything seems to be working, EXCEPT I don't see my RAID 1 drive.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: It should pick up the drive just fine if you installed the HBA drivers.

Comment: Guess that's the part I missed, is there a way to go add them after the fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Chris S pointed me in the right direction, I was still unable to see the RAID with DISKPART on the server, so I gave the pnputil a try after reading this post

http://www.davidorlo.com/articles/virtual-machine/installing-drivers-in-hyper-v-server

and that worked, DISKPART recognized the drive so I was home free. I in the process of creating VMs on the RAID 1 as I type this.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 2):

To add drivers to a VHD image:

1. Mount the image on Win7 or Server2008 machine (Disk Management, right click the tree and attach the VHD; make sure it assigns a drive letter).
2. Extract the drivers to someplace convenient, like `c:\drivers`; make sure the `.inf` file was extracted to that directory.
3. Run `dism /image:G:\ /add-driver /driver:C:\drivers\storage.inf`
   Replace G: with the drive of the VHD file from #1.
   Replace the inf file with the file found in #2.
4. Dismount (Find in Disk Management, right click drive, detach VHD)